# Cordova needs xcodebuild version 9.0.0 or greater

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working on an Ionic 3 project and I'm trying to build the app on ios, my Xcode version is 7.3.1 and it's the lastest version supported by my mac ( MacBook Air 2015: OS X El Capitan )

When I try to build ios with my Ionic 3 App I get this Error :

```
Cordova needs xcodebuild version 9.0.0 or greater, you have version 7.3.1. Please install version 9.0.0 or greater from App Store
```

Is there any solution other than upgrading my Mac?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, my only solution was to download MacOS MOJAVE and install it.
After that i updated Xcode and Ionic and it was working.

https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos